# Elementary substructures of $H_{\kappa^+}$.

Tags: set-theory

This is surely a dumb question, but I can't find the mistake and it's driving me insane:

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal

First, the following is true:

> If $x\in H_{\kappa^+}$ and $f:x\to H_{\kappa^+}$ then $f\in H_{\kappa^+}$.

Consider $M\preceq H_{\kappa^+}$.

Let $x\in M$. Since $M\subset H_{\kappa^+}$, $|x|\le \kappa$, so that there is some $f:\kappa \twoheadrightarrow x$. Any such $f$ must lie in $H_{\kappa^+}$ by the above, so
$$
H_{\kappa^+}\models \exists f:\kappa\twoheadrightarrow x
$$
Now, $\kappa\in M$, since $\kappa$ is definable in $H_{\kappa^+}$ as the largest cardinal. Therefore, by elementarity,
$$
M\models\exists f:\kappa\twoheadrightarrow x
$$
Pick $f\in M$ such that $M\models f:\kappa\twoheadrightarrow x$. Then $x=f''\kappa\subset M$, so $M$ is transitive.

Now, this is obviously impossible (take $M$ small), but I can't seem to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Does $\kappa\subset M$? Otherwise, all you have is $f[\kappa\cap M]\subseteq M$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Ah, of course, you're totally right! My reasoning was that, if $y\in x$, then $y=f(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha<\kappa$, but I needn't have $\alpha\in M$ to get $f(\alpha)\in M$ by definability. Thanks a lot! I was starting to doubt my sanity! Thinking of the case $\kappa=\omega$, where this is true, things work because every natural number is definable without parameters.